# IE7 – annoying delay after opening new tab

Tags: browser, browser-tabs, internet-explorer-7

I liked the idea of tabbed browsing when IE7 came out. However, when I press Ctrl+T (new tab) IE opens new tab, and for some time it becomes irresponsible, new tab is displaying “Connecting”. This happens even with default page set do “about:blank”. In fact, this IE7 behavior made me to switch to FireFox and left some of my machines with IE6.

Do you know why this delay occurs?

Comment: Have you tried IE8?

Comment: This actually happens to me also and I run IE8 on Windows 7. It's the biggest reason I don't use it.

I have no idea why it happens.

Comment: Any reason you still need IE?

Comment: Actually I was serious, if it's only in IE but not in Chrome/Firefox/Safari/Opera well then go for those!

Comment: I just figured you for an IE hater!

Comment: Since I switched to Firefox, I use it almost exclusively. However, I still use sometimes IE to access some sites. And occasionaly Opera and Chrome - to check how my websites look in different browsers.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: On Windows 7 with IE8 I have a consistent 1 second pause to create a new tab, really annoying.  I have NO add-ons (I never use IE except for sites that require it).

Answer (score 4):

Your problem could be related to your IE addons or also if you have a long restricted sites list (tools -> security -> restricted sites):

Check Microsoft's [How to make IE open new tabs faster](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/07/18/how-to-make-ie-open-new-tabs-faster.aspx):

> Add-ons are loaded by IE when you open a new browser window or tab. This is usually a quick process, but certain add-ons may cause IE to take a longer time than expected. For example, after installing Skype 4.1, this user (and his father) encountered a slowdown in IE on their computers.
>
> [..]
>
> Examine the performance impact of your add-ons using the Manage Add-ons dialog. Click on Tools - Manage Add-ons, and look at the ‘Load time’ column.
>
> [..]
>
> If you do not want to keep a slow loading add-on around, you can disable it, and it won’t be loaded the next time you open a new window or tab. You can also open Add/Remove Programs and remove IE add-ons that you are not using. This removes the add-on for all users on the computer.

If your problem is not related to your addons, then use this file (from [Adding unwanted sites to the Internet Explorer Restricted Zone](http://www.mvps.org/winhelp2002/restricted.htm)) to delete all your restricted sites:

http://www.mvps.org/winhelp2002/DelDomains.inf (right-click -> install)

Comment: The first is a very good link, a must-read for every IE8 user, even for those who're not experiencing slow loads.

Comment: I tried to read that link today and I can't get the site to open up.

Comment: I have the same new tab delay with IE8 on Windows XP. This is a fresh install, no add-ons, no Flash, nothing. Yet it still has a delay and says "connecting". What is it connecting to anyways?

Answer (score 2):

Is this being caused by any Anti-virus or Spyware monitoring software?

Comment: I'll check it...

Comment: Or, I guess more likely: being caused by some malware itself (like some so-called search add-on that replaces ads?). A good scan may surely help. (Or look into Options and then somewhere find the installed "objects" or something like that.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have that problem with IE7 running on Vista. When I ctrl+t or click empty tab box on toolbar I get a new tab really quick with url of about:blank. Do you get the same behaviour if you click the new tab box at the end of your open tabs on the toolbar? Did you reset all your IE options back to default and try it again?

UPDATE:
I do see this problem running IE8 on Windows 7 RTM. If I try to open a new tab using the tab button, Sometimes it works directly and other times it actually takes 30 seconds while IE becomes unresponsive and then I actually get a new browser window. If I right click on a link and select open in new tab, it takes 30 seconds also and then opens a new window. Really wierd!

Comment: Yes, I did. And again, again.

Comment: Check your "Connections" tab under Internet Options and see if you have something like Automatic Configuration turned on or it is trying to dial a connection ( I had a VPN that it would try and fire up first even though I didn't need it ). My similiar problem went away after I changed it to "never dial a connection"

Answer (score 1):

To know for sure what it is connecting to, you could use a packet sniffer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), or (a bit easier to use I guess) a debugging proxy such as [Fiddler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250446(VS.85).aspx).

(By the way: Firefox, not FireFox -- just one uppercase F.)

Answer (score 1):

Try starting IE with extensions/addons disabled:

**Run>iexplore -extoff**

Do you have spybot installed on the machines?

Comment: Yes, I have SPybot S&D installed.

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the "Automatically detect settings" checkbox in Internet Options -> Connections tab -> LAN settings

Comment: Also, try going to Control Panel -> Internet Options -> click "Settings" near Tabs (where it says Change how webpages are displayed in tabs) -> and then where it says "When a new tab is opened, open:" set it to "A blank page" instead of the "The new tab page".